# how to escape @ in string variable while using awk

Tags: shell, awk

```
$a = 262145_73236692@10.54.87.31    
awk -F',' '$2 == $a {print $1}' file.csv
```

This is my command.
It shows syntax error at '@' Its not working because  i have '@' character in my string..
How do i make it work so that it wwill exactly match my string including special character. $a is a looping variable which is iterating thru an array of strings and matching it with a file file.csv

Comment: Could you provide your original error message?

Comment: using double quotes is working. i wss getting syntax error at @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you cannot use bash variables inside AWK programs.

To prove this, you can run the next commands:

```
export a="262145_73236692@10.54.87.31"
awk -v A=$a 'BEGIN {print "bash: " $a; print "awk:  " A}' file.csv
```

If your output is:

```
bash:  
awk:  262145_73236692@10.54.87.31
```

– it shows you that $a has empty value inside AWK. (And that's understandable if you consider what operator `$` does in AWK.)

Therefore correct solutions for you would be:

```
export a="262145_73236692@10.54.87.31"
awk -v A=$a -F',' '$2 == A {print $1}' file.csv
```

Or simpler:

```
awk -v A="262145_73236692@10.54.87.31" -F',' '$2 == A {print $1}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess using a back slash \ before the @ symbol should work.

Comment: Actually using double quotes is working..i need to insert double quotes in $a .Using \ symbol is not working

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by using double quotes.

Comment: `$a = "123"` makes a variable in bash on your machine? :-O It doesn't work on mine. What operation system are you using?